# Loading specific translations with Globalize3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, globalize3

Is it possible to load a specific translation with Globalize 3?

For instance, I have a `Post` which is translatable and shows on the front end in the correct locale as it should.  However, I want to show a this same version in the admin which has a fixed locale of :en.

One way of doing this seems to be by telling what locale we're in:

```
Globalize.locale = :de
Post.where(id: params[:id])
```

works just fine, but that's going to be overriding the locale globally.

So, how can I request the specific locale for just this one instance?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Globalize.with_locale` in the view:

```
- Globalize.with_locale(:de) do
  = debug @post
```